# Are entity_id and order_id the same in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database

I am creating a module that is going to save orders to a .csv file. The problem now is that I need both the name of the product and the name of the customer. As far as I know these are not stored in the same mysql table. I can get the customer name form the "sales_order" table and the product name form the "sales_order_item". "sales_order" has an id called "entity_id" and "sales_order_item" has an id called "order_id". Are these ids the same?

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they both are same. Magento saves order in `sales_order` table and products of order are stored in `sales_order_item` and `order_id` in `sales_order_item` table connects that product to its order from `sales_order` table having  `entity_id` same as `order_id` .